# Is this normal happening?

Tags: eclipse

I used Eclipse, and tried to make some new training programs, but when I compiled one, eclipse was running very slow, and then when I see the percents in the Task manager, it showed 2 task, javaw ( I don't know the exactly name ) was running on 50-50%. Can it be damage my processor or something? What can I do against this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dual-core computer and a process that's taking 50%, it means it's using one core, at its maximum capability.

Compiling is a complex operation ; and it doesn't surprise me that it'd use a full CPU for some time *(depending on the size of your project)*.

Using a CPU at its maximum, a bad thing ? Well, if you have a CPU, why not just use it ;-)

I don't think it can damage anything, at least if that doesn't last *too long* and your CPU is properly cooled.

I've had my quad-core CPU run at 100% *(on each core)* for several days in a row ; I've seen absolutly no problem since *(the fans were working harder for that time, but it's all)*

`jawaw` is the process that corresponds to the execution of JAVA *(at least for some programs)* ; and Eclipse is developped in JAVA ; so no surprise here either.

Comment: Yeah, I know it, but It wasn't happened to me yet. But, if you say It's not a problem, I calmed down. :) (I wrote only a small program)

Comment: If jawaw is the actual program execution, maybe there's an infinite loop spinning in the program?

Comment: It could be happen, but my program didn't run exactly until my CPU was on 100%. I interrupted the javaw s and restarted the computer. My CPU fan is on 6800 RPM. I hope it is normal :)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar behavior when certain Anti-virus programs start scanning files being generated by the compiler.

Try adding your workspace folder to an "ignore" list on your virus scan software.